# How do I make the 'make' command work?

Tags: makefile

I am trying "Linux Kernel Module Programming - Compiling the Module" as in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8hifIrDh-g) youtube video.

First I created a `hello.c` program. Then I used the command `#gedit Makefile`. It opens a window which is empty in gedit.

I tried to copy the same commands but running make command

it showed an error:

```
make:*** No rule to make target 'make', needed by 'all'. Stop.
```

Searching some Ubuntu forms I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install build essentials 
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake
```

Every time I executed this command some packages got installed.

I went and checked in:

```
root@ubuntu: /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build
```

I can see 'Makefile' when typed `ls` command,  but still I have the same problem
`make` command is not still working as `gedit Makefile` command open a blank editor.

Comment: the error you get point to a mistake in your Makefile, could you paste your Makefile here?

Comment: It seems like you are running `make make` or something like that (instead of just `make`). Can you paste the exact command you are executing?

Answer (score 1):

As Gerhard says, it's a problem with the makefile.

In the video, the author has prepared a makefile, and so you need to copy his instructions into your own make file.

I tried his instructions myself and made sure to copy the Makefile exactly, which worked well, so if you check your file carefully for errors, you will hopefully find it. Here's my file, that works, you could save some time by copying it instead.

```
obj-m += hello.o

KDIR=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-22-generic/

all:
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
rm -rf *.ko *.o *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

One thing to watch out for with Makefiles, that isn't mentioned in the video, is that in this part

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

The `$(MAKE)` line must be indented with a TAB, *not* spaces.